# Python 2.7.10 Pygame 1.9.1. I'm trying to change the values of a list by 5 either increasing or decreasing

Tags: python, windows, pygame

```
import pygame, sys, random, math, os
from random import randint, uniform
from pygame.locals import*
from locations import*
pygame.init()

brick=pygame.image.load("resources/images/brick.png")
cave_block=pygame.image.load("resources/images/cave_block1.jpg")
background=pygame.image.load("resources/images/bg.png")
player_img=pygame.image.load("resources/images/spaceship.png")
screenX=1024
screenY=768
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((screenX,screenY))
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
game=True

block_top=0
block_bottom=0
block_left=0

make_top=[(0,0)]
make_bottom=[(0,704)]
make_left=[(0,64)]

cave_top=0
make_cave_top=[(0,0)]

move_playerU=False
move_playerL=False
move_playerD=False
move_playerR=False
cave=[(640,400)]

backgrounS_pos=([0,0])
player_imgS_pos=([512,384])
```

the lists i want to change, they are positions for where to blit images.

it would also be nice to have these lists saved in another file and read from there while still being changeable.

```
cave_block1S_pos=([(0,0),(32,0),(64,0),(96,0),(128,0),(160,0),(192,0),(224,0),(256,0),(288,0),(320,0),(352,0),(384,0),(416,0),(448,0),(480,0),(512,0),(544,0),(576,0),(608,0),(640,0),(672,0),(704,0),(736,0),(768,0),(800,0),(832,0),(864,0),(896,0),(928,0),(960,0),(992,0),(1024,0)])
cave_block2S_pos=([(0,736),(32,736),(64,736),(96,736),(128,736),(160,736),(192,736),(224,736),(256,736),(288,736),(320,736),(352,736),(384,736),(416,736),(448,736),(480,736),(512,736),(544,736),(576,736),(608,736),(640,736),(672,736),(704,736),(736,736),(768,736),(800,736),(832,736),(864,736),(896,736),(928,736),(960,736),(992,736),(1024,736)])
cave_block3S_pos=([(0,0),(0,32),(0,64),(0,96),(0,128),(0,160),(0,192),(0,224),(0,256),(0,288),(0,320),(0,352),(0,384),(0,416),(0,448),(0,480),(0,512),(0,544),(0,576),(0,608),(0,640),(0,672),(0,704),(0,736),(0,768)])

while game:
    clock.tick(30)
    screen.blit(background,(backgrounS_pos))
    screen.blit(player_img,(player_imgS_pos))
```

where i'm trying to change the values of the list.

```
    for blocks in cave_block1S_pos:
        screen.blit(cave_block,blocks)
        if move_playerR==True:
            cave_block1S_pos[0]-=5

    for blocks in cave_block2S_pos:
        screen.blit(cave_block,blocks)
    for blocks in cave_block3S_pos:
        screen.blit(cave_block,blocks)

#cave.append([random.randint(player_imgS_pos[0]-512,player_imgS_pos[1]+684), random.randint(player_imgS_pos[0]-512,player_imgS_pos[0]+384)])
    #for rocks in cave:
        #screen.blit(cave_block, rocks)
        #if move_playerR==True:
            #rocks[0]+=5

    if backgrounS_pos[0]>=32:
        backgrounS_pos[0]=32

    if backgrounS_pos[0]<=-905:
        backgrounS_pos[0]=-905

    if backgrounS_pos[1]>=32:
        backgrounS_pos[1]=32

    if backgrounS_pos[1]<=-470:
        backgrounS_pos[1]=-470

    if move_playerR==True:
        backgrounS_pos[0]-=5

    if move_playerL==True:
        backgrounS_pos[0]+=5

    if move_playerD==True:
        backgrounS_pos[1]-=5

    if move_playerU==True:
        backgrounS_pos[1]+=5

    print(backgrounS_pos)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                exit(0)

            if event.key==K_w:
                move_playerU=True

            if event.key==K_a:
                move_playerL=True

            if event.key==K_s:
                move_playerD=True

            if event.key==K_d:
                move_playerR=True

        if event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key==K_w:
                move_playerU=False

            if event.key==K_a:
                move_playerL=False

            if event.key==K_s:
                move_playerD=False

            if event.key==K_d:
                move_playerR=False

        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit
            exit(0)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? You change the values by 5, and then what happens?

Comment: you mean `backgrounS_pos` never changes right? if so can you print the values of the `move_playerxxx` booleans?

Comment: I`m unable to change the values because of an error. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'tuple' and 'int'

Comment: backgroundS_pos  changes when  the if statements become true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cave_block1S_pos[0] -= 5` is the same as `cave_block1S_pos[0] = cave_block1S_pos[0] - 5`, which in your case is `cave_block1S_pos[0] = (0, 0) - 5`. You cannot subtract 5 from a tuple, hence gets the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'tuple' and 'int'`